# Upgrade pandas in a specific location

Tags: python, pandas

I have both python 2 and 3 installed on my computer. When using python 3, pandas is up to date, but when using python 2 I am stuck at version 0.12.0. When I try "pip install --upgrade pandas," I get a message that it is already up to date in the python 3 location. Is there a way to specify where I want it to upgrade? Thanks!

Comment: That's why you need [virtual environment](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).